# VideoView in Android

Tags: android

I am using VideoView in Android for displaying streaming videos.
While playing the videos if a user receives & disconnects the call ,the video starts playing from beginning instead of the behavior which should be that after the call disconnection ,the video should start playing from the same place when the call was received.

Kindly provide your suggestions/sample code if you have already implemented the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not tried this, but this is where I would start:

Step #1: In `onStop()`, call `getCurrentPosition()` on the VideoView and save the value.

Step #2: In `onStart()`, call `getCurrentPosition()` on the `VideoView` and compare it to the value from Step #1. If they differ (e.g., `getCurrentPosition()` is now `0`), call `seekTo()`, supplying the value from Step #1.

Step #3: In `onSaveInstanceState()`, call `getCurrentPosition()` on the `VideoView` and store the value in the supplied `Bundle`.

Step #4: In `onRestoreInstanceState()`, obtain the value from Step #3 from the supplied `Bundle` and put it in the data member used by Step #1 and Step #2.

This should cover you for the relevant scenarios that might occur while the phone call is going on.

Comment: I spent a few hours today working on something similar, but getCurrentPosition() sporadically returns 0 for me when the seek position is not zero.

Comment: in onPause() videoview getCurrentPosition returns proper value but in onStop it returns 0. Any idea why?

Comment: @Swati: No, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look at the [life of an activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife). Make sure you handle the onStart() and onStop() well, starting the video in the same place.

[VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) has an getCurrentPosition() and seekTo(), those should help to get the spot set right.

Good luck!